# Write xml in root

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, directory

I'm currently trying to write a XML file in ASP.Net (see code below). It is not the writing that doesn't work, but when I run the code, it returns an error: `Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\devices.xml' is denied.`

This is not the directory of my project, so I don't know why it's trying to save the XML right there.

If this is the problem of the error, how do I make sure the XML is saving to my project root? Else, what is wrong here and what do I have to do?

**Code**

```
ArrayList devices = new ArrayList();
devices.Add(new Device());

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("devices.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument();

foreach(Device device in devices)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("device");

    writer.WriteStartElement("name");
    writer.WriteString(device.name);
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: did u try using the current directory? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method to get the current directory and than combine that with your file name to store it in your project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use **Server.MapPath()** to get the proper path to where your application is running, so:

```
new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("~/devices.xml"), Encoding.UTF8);
```

See if that helps you?

Comment: It probably works, but it says `Server does not exists`.. I've tried `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: did u try using the current directory?  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method to get the current directory and than combine that with your file name to store it in your project folder

Comment: Server.MapPath() should work - in your debugging you may have to use a local IIS instead of the VS built-in server. If it's a self-hosting app, then I am not sure

Comment: @Meghaa Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() gives me the same directory: `C:\Program Files\IIS Express`.. @Pedro G. Dias It can't find `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` for some reason

Comment: That means your program is running from "C:\Program Files\IIS Express" .

Comment: You can try a trick...In your debugger..go to Project-> Properties and in the debug section, set your working directory to your project directory and than see what happens when you try to get the current directory

Comment: @Meghaa See comment at your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your working directory or current working directory is set to "C:\Program Files\IIS Express" . To solve this what you can do is in the debugger , go to Project -> Project properties -> Debug . Set the working directory to the location you want your xml file to be saved and run the program. This will create the XML file in your desired location.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like my problem indeed, but where do I have to specify that? https://gyazo.com/c08146fcfb8237c29be85568bd8b8743.png That's the only place I'm seeing 'IIS Express'

Comment: Just above startUrl, you have an option of setting the working directory. Set the directory there.